# Prove this isomorphism of $K$-algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Seen this is a lot of literature, usually without proof. Was just wondering how is it:

> $A$ is a $K$-algebra, where $K$ is a field. Then $A \otimes_K A^{op} \simeq M_r(K)$ where $r=\dim(A)$.

I guess we first pick a basis of $A/A^{op}$... Not really seeing where $a \otimes a'$ maps to...

Thanks.

Additional question:

> Also $A \otimes_K K \simeq A$?

Comment: What is $A$ module, algebra, over field, ring?

Comment: Yes sorry I should have clarified this.

Comment: $dim_k(A\otimes_k A^{op})= dim_k(A)^2$ and $dim_k(M_r(A))=r^2dim(A)$

Comment: $\phi :A\otimes k\rightarrow A$, $\phi: a\otimes i\mapsto ai$ is algebra isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-algebra. There is an isomorphism of vector spaces $A^* \otimes_K A \cong \mathrm{End}_K(A)$ (which is then isomorphic to $M_r(K)$ if $r=\dim_K(A)$) given by $\phi \otimes a \mapsto \phi(-) \cdot a$. But the right hand side is a $K$-algebra, so what is the induced multiplication on the left hand side?

The product of $\phi \otimes a$ and $\psi \otimes b$ is the preimage of $(\phi(-) \cdot a) \circ (\psi(-) \cdot b)$ which maps $x \in A$ to $\phi(\psi(x)b)a=\psi(x) \phi(b)a$. Hence, the product on $A^* \otimes_K A$ is given by
$$(\phi \otimes a) \cdot (\psi \otimes b) = \psi \otimes \phi(b)a.$$
I don't think that this algebra is isomorphic to $A \otimes_K A^{op}$.

But we have a homomorphism of $K$-algebras
$$A \otimes_K A^{op} \to \mathrm{End}_K(A),~ a \otimes b \mapsto (x \mapsto axb).$$
If $A$ is *central simple*, then this homomorphism is an isomorphism (see [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/074I)).

Comment: Not sure I understand your point. If $A\simeq A^*\simeq A^{op}$ (which could happen), then $A\otimes_K A^{op}\simeq \mathrm{End}_K(A)$, no?

Comment: As $K$-vector spaces, but not as algebras (and $A^*$ is not an algebra unless $A$ is also a bialgebra).

Comment: I still don't understand. Of course I did not mean as vector spaces... Yes, $A^*$ can be an algebra... Anyway, what you have added contains the trivial case I had in mind, namely $A=V^*\otimes V\simeq L(V)$ for some finite-dimensional vector space $V$.